# Elaborating menu with bash scripts that use source

Tags: bash

I got these two scripts, `configScript.sh` and `genScript.sh`, which works exactly as I want. `configScript.sh` sets up the options to use the next time I run `genScript.sh` in the shell.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#configScript.sh
func()
{
echo "
Choose
1 - Option 1
2 - Option 2
"
echo -n "   Enter selection: "
read select
case $select in
            1 ) 
            echo "  Option 1 chosen"
            . ./genScript.sh one
            cat << EOF >options.sh
OPTION=$OPTION
EOF
            ;;
            2 )
            echo "  Option 2 chosen"
            . ./genScript.sh two
            cat << EOF >options.sh
OPTION=$OPTION
EOF
            ;;

esac
}
func
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#genScript.sh
OPTION=""
. options.sh
[ "$1" ] && OPTION=$1
func2()
{
    if [ "$OPTION" == one ] ; then
        echo "Option one"
    elif [ "$OPTION" == two ] ; then
        echo "Option two"
    else
        echo "null"
    fi
}
func2
```

---

My problem is that I want to change my menu in `configScript.sh` into something like this:

---

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#configScript.sh
func()
{
echo "
Choose
1 - foo
2 - bar 
"
echo -n "   Enter selection: "
read select
case $select in
            1 ) 
            echo "  foo chosen"
            foo
            ;;
            2 )
            echo "  bar chosen"
            bar
            ;;      
esac
}

foo()
{
    echo "
    Choose
    1 - foo1
    2 - foo2
    "
    echo -n "    Enter Selection: "
    read fooSelect
    case $fooSelect in
        1 )
        echo "foo1 chosen"
        ;;
        2 )
        echo "foo2 chosen"
        ;;
    esac
}

bar()
{
        echo "
    Choose
    1 - bar1
    2 - bar2
    "
    echo -n " Enter Selection: "
    read barSelect
    case $barSelect in
        1 )
        echo "bar1 chosen"
        ;;
        2 )
        echo "bar2 chosen"
        ;;
    esac
}
func
```

---

Where can I put in the segment to write the chosen option over to `options.sh`? This part:

```
. ./genScript.sh one
cat << EOF >options.sh
OPTION=$OPTION
EOF
```

If I keep them within the `foo()` and `bar()` it should mean that if I configure to echo `foo1` and then to echo `bar2` my `genScript.sh` should only output one of them. How can I solve this?

Update*
I'll try and make it a bit more clear. If I haven't run any scripts `options.sh` will be empty. If I then run `configScript.sh` and choose the option that echoes `foo2` and then the option that echoes `bar1` and then close down 'configscript.sh`. After that I run`genScript.sh`and I want it to echo`foo2`and`bar1`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you save your OPTION to option.sh instead of passing it's value as a second argument to genscript.sh ?

Comment: Yes because I want `genScript.sh` to remember the values if I run it by itself in a shell.

Comment: `genScript.sh` will always output one of them because `cat << EOF >options.sh` will overwrite the previous contents of `options.sh` which is what you want. You will always have only the latest choice made in `options.sh`

Comment: I want it to store both of the options if I choose to update two of them. How can I do this?

Comment: @thom Updated the question to try and make it a bit more clear what m looking for.

Comment: if you select `foo` for first `read select`, why should you reach `bar1` any time?

Comment: @anishsane First I do `foo` --> `foo2`. Then I do it again but go `bar` --> `bar1`

Comment: So you want to store 3 variables: `select=foo` or `select=bar`, `selectfoo=foo1 or foo2`, `selectbar=bar1 or bar2`. Right?

Comment: It's enough with `select=foo1` or `select=foo2` or `select=bar1` or `select=bar2`

Comment: I have created something (see answer). Tell me if it does not do what you want and tell me how it differs from what you want.

Comment: @Benji, which one do you mean `I want it to store both of the options if I choose to update two of them` or `It's enough with select=foo1 or select=foo2 or select=bar1 or select=bar2` . These two sentences are mutual exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configscript:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#configScript.sh
func()
{
    . options.sh
    echo "
    Choose
    1 - foo
    2 - bar 
    3 - update config
    "
    echo -n "   Enter selection: "
    read select
    case $select in
        1 ) echo "  foo chosen"    ; foo ;;
        2 ) echo "  bar chosen"    ; bar ;;      
        3 ) echo "  update chosen" ; update ;; 
    esac
}

update()
{
cat <<EOF >options.sh
FOO=$FOO
BAR=$BAR 
EOF

. ./genScript.sh
}

foo()
{
    echo "
    Choose
    1 - foo1
    2 - foo2
    "
    echo -n "    Enter Selection: "
    read fooSelect
    case $fooSelect in
        1 ) echo "foo1 chosen" ; FOO="foo1" ;;
        2 ) echo "foo2 chosen" ; FOO="foo2" ;;
    esac
}

bar()
{
    echo "
    Choose
    1 - bar1
    2 - bar2
    "
    echo -n " Enter Selection: "
    read barSelect
    case $barSelect in
        1 ) echo "bar1 chosen" ; BAR="bar1" ;;
        2 ) echo "bar2 chosen" ; BAR="bar2" ;;
    esac
}
func
```

Your genScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#genScript.sh
FOO=""
BAR=""
. options.sh
[ "$1" ] && FOO=$1
[ "$2" ] && BAR=$2
func2()
{
    echo $FOO
    echo $BAR
}
func2
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! I just need to investigate a bit more how I can adapt this format to my actual code.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question als "solved" if you are happy with the answer.

Comment: I've done some thorough testing and it this solution is just as good as expected

Comment: I have ran into a problem now. It works great if I run `configScript.sh` and set `foo1` and `bar2` and then update. Then the script will echo both `foo1` and `bar2`. But if I then run `configScript.sh` and only set `foo2` and then update, the script will write `FOO=foo2` and `BAR=` to `options.sh`. Is it possible to keep the options I previously set?

Comment: I have updated accordingly. What I added is the first line in `func()`